# How do I increment or decrement object property in state management?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am making use of NGRX and I need to increment or decrement a value in an object.

Below is my initial state

```
const initialState: ProductState = {
  Products: [],
  ActiveProduct: null,
  pageInfo: { pageNumber: 1, pageSize: 6, totalPages: 0, totalRecords: 0 },
};
```

My aim is to add 1 or subtract 1 from `pageNumber` inside `pageInfo`. I have the follwowing function to try and achieve this:

```
export function ProductReducer(state = initialState, action: ProductActions) {
switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_PAGE_NUMBER:
      return {
        ...state.pageInfo,
        pageNumber: state.pageInfo.pageNumber + 1
      }

    case SUBTRACT_PAGE_NUMBER:
      return {
        ...state.pageInfo,
        pageNumber: state.pageInfo.pageNumber - 1
      }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Yep seems fine. Is there a reason you cannot use createReducer btw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your reducer you are returning only the "pageInfo" object, whereas your reducer should always return the entire state, you can achieve this by changing your code to the following :

```
export function ProductReducer(state = initialState, action: ProductActions) {
switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_PAGE_NUMBER:
      return {
        ...state,
        pageInfo : {
           ...state.pageInfo,
           pageNumber: state.pageInfo.pageNumber + 1
        }
      }

    case SUBTRACT_PAGE_NUMBER:
      return {
        ...state,
        pageInfo : {
           ...state.pageInfo,
           pageNumber: state.pageInfo.pageNumber - 1
        }
      }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
 }
}
```